# Opinions on recurring (not duplicate) questions?

Tags: discussion

Some questions are structured in such a way that they could be asked in the future, and get a completely different answer.  For example, "[Who's "winning" with launch rate?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31794/26446)" was recently asked.  It's a valid question, and has a good answer.  However, the answer could be very different if the question was asked next year, or in 5 years.

I call such questions "recurring" questions.  This is to be distinguished from a duplicate question, which will continue to have the same answer (at least as long as technology stays the same).  Duplicate questions don't add anything to this site, but an argument can be made that recurring questions do.  I have several related meta questions about your opinions toward recurring questions:

1. Do you consider this to be an issue?
2. What should be the appropriate response to a new question that is a recurrence of an older question?  (e.g. let it go, put year in title, link to old question as recurrence, ask to reword question, or close as duplicate)
3. What should be the appropriate response to a new question unrelated to an older question, but has the potential to become recurring in the future?
4. How often should recurrence of a given question be allowed?

Comment: Related: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/795/58

Comment: @called2voyage: I thought I had seen this posted in meta before!  But I spent an hour trying to find it and didn't, so I created this post.  Anyways, this new post goes a bit further than the previous one.

Comment: I'm going to close my own meta question, as follow-up should occur in the post linked by @called2voyage.  However, please don't delete this question, as I couldn't find the other post, so this question will be a signpost to it.

Comment: It looks like I had a 3 day and 12 hour opportunity to add an answer here specific to the example, but no mention of it was left at my question I was never flagged. A similar point was made [as a direct comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31856/which-has-been-the-most-gregarious-rocket-launched-from-the-most-sites#comment96527_31856) on another recent question of mine [Which has been the most gregarious rocket, launched from the most sites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31856/12102) (rather than off in metaland). I thought about it, and rewrote the question to suit.

Comment: If I had been told about the question here, I would have posted an answer citing this example and saying that **1.** Many questions in rapidly changing fields will have answers that become obsolete in a few years, wether they are "structured in such a way" or not. SE has excellent time-stamping and edit history, inherited from SO where things are always changing. The SE system has our back, trust it. **2.** If it’s still a problem somehow, or you think there’s a better way, comment to the OP with a friendly, helpful suggestion. (continued)

Comment: (cont.) That may be all it takes, and keeping the solution local and immediate is better than generating a policy. **3.** Even if you don’t want to, if you’ve asked a meta question about a specific post, make a note of that such that the post-writer will be notified. Otherwise it could look like your hoping they won’t find out. Many people don’t comb through meta daily or have some other notification mechanism, but may have a relevant contribution to share.

Comment: Voting to *temporarily re-open* this question long enough for me to convert the above comments into an answer, then I'll re-vote to close as duplicate because the answers to the general topic there still apply nicely.

Comment: @uhoh: Good points.  Is there a reason why you wouldn't post them as an answer on the older meta question?

Comment: Yes, some of it has obvious specificity to this question, some less obviously.